# Can I install Microsoft Visual Basic 6 in a Windows 2008 R2 Server?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

I mean, not specifically the Runtime Library but the whole VB 6 IDE.

Comment: At my job we have a Vb6 app (COM+, Oracle) running on a Windows 2000 server, but as a part of a technology replacement plan, a new Windows 2008 R2 server is going to be bought.  So our app must be migrated to this new server (so we're going to need VB6 in order to compile the server components).

Answer (score 3):

According to [this article on Softpedia](http://news.softpedia.com/news/Visual-Basic-6-0-on-Windows-7-but-Not-on-Windows-8-105474.shtml), it should work. Try it and let us know.

Answer (score 0):

Visual basic Supports all versions of Windows, including Windows 9x, ME, XP, Vista, 7, and their server editions.

Comment: I use VB6 on Windows 7 to support some legacy apps. There should be nothing in the server version (2008 R2) that would cause it to be incompatible.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain The 64bitness.

Comment: @kinokijuf no, my windows 7 is 64 bit and vb6 runs fine on it.

Answer (score 0):

No. Visual Studio 6 does not work on 64-bit editions of Windows.

> [The Visual Basic 6.0 IDE has never been offered in a native 64-bit version, nor has the 32-bit IDE been supported on 64-bit Windows. VB6 development on 64-bit Windows or any native architecture other than 32-bit is not and will not be supported.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/nb-no/vbrun/ms788708(en-us).aspx)

Comment: Except it is supported.  This chart says otherwise: http://msdn.microsoft.com/nb-no/vbrun/ms788708(en-us).aspx I don't think the author honestly expects the IDE to continue to work in 2008 R2.

Comment: It says exactly the opposite: “VB6 development on 64-bit Windows or any native architecture other than 32-bit is not and will not be supported”.

Comment: @kinokijuf It seems to me that by "not supported", the documentation does not necessarily mean "does not work", but rather that no support will be offered in case of problems. From the beginning of the article: "The Visual Basic 6.0 IDE is no longer supported as of April 8, 2008. /---/ both the Windows and Visual Basic teams have tested Visual Basic 6.0 IDE on Windows Vista, Windows 7, Windows Server 2008, and Windows 8 to understand and mitigate (if appropriate) serious regressions in application compatibility."

Comment: @Indrek IIRC VS6 requires MS Java, which does not work on 64-bit Windows.